# Filtering numbers above a certain threshold for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a data set with with 600+ variables and I would like to only keep the rows where the values in multiple columns are above a certain threshold, in my case >= 5,000,000.

For a single column I would filter like this:

```
df <- df %>%
  filter(variable.2019.03 >= 5000000)
```

I could do it for multiple columns like this:

```
df <- df %>%
  filter(variable.2019.03 >= 5000000 & variable.2019.04 >= 5000000 &
         variable.2019.05 >= 5000000)
```

However, I want to do this for 30+ columns so I was hoping there is a more elegant way. My understanding is that I should be able to do this using the filter() function in combination with if_all(), but I was only able to find example where these functions are used to filter character columns nor numeric ones. Similar to the examples [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/), I have tried:

```
  filter(if_all(>= 5000000), variable.2019.03:variable.2022.03)
```

which only yielded this error message:

```
Error: unexpected '>=' in:
"df <- df %>%
  filter(if_all(>="
```

Any suggestions on achieving the desired outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to specify the columns (`.cols`) within the `if_all`.  By default it is `everything()`, so we change to match only the columns that starts with (`^`) 'variable' followed by a dot (`.`), four digits (`\\d{4}`)..., within the `matches` (that uses regular expression to match the column names)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(if_all(matches('^variable\\.\\d{4}\\.d{2}$'), ~ .x >= 5000000))
```

If the columns are adjacent, we can use `:`

```
df %>%
    filter(if_all(variable.2019.03:variable.2022.03, ~ .x >= 5000000))
```